# Check for nil with int fields from struct?

Tags: go, struct, error-handling

I have this code and I am trying to check for nil on point.x, point.y, size.width, size.height (and return an error if there is nil) before I pass it into the compare structs function. I keep running into errors every which way I try it and I can't help to think that I'm completely overthinking it.

Comment: `nil` is not a valid value for `int`.  Is there's an invalid value for those x, y, width and height in your application, then initialize the fields with the invalid value and test for that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check for nil because an int cannot possibly be nil in Go.  If you don't explicitly initialize it, it will have the value of 0.

You expressed concern in a now-deleted comment that you'll encounter runtime errors because of this.  You will not, but you may not have the intended behavior.

If 0 is not a valid value for your domain, you can simply check for 0.

Otherwise, if you want to make things more explicit, you can make it so someone can only initialize the values by calling a function you wrote and only publicly exposing the values through a getter (making the values immutable).